# Getting Trigger batch Save error on KB Articles which doesn't support triggers

Tags: approval-process, articles

I am getting an error "*Too many retries of batch save in the presence of Apex triggers with failures: when triggers are present partial save requires that some subset of rows save without any errors in order to avoid inconsistent side effects from those triggers. Number of retries: 2", when clicking on Approve button in Approval Process. The Approval Process is on Articles(Knowledge) which by it self doesn't support triggers. There are a few field updates on the approval process and I click on Approve link 1 at a time.
Have any body come across such an error, what can be a potential fix.

Comment: The response from SFDC Support is that, the data may be corrupted. Even they are not able to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 1):

Our problem was with some Referential Links in certain articles had a space at the end of the link within the Quotes. If you remove the space at the end of the article link, the article will go into the approval process without the error. For Example,

`<a href="/articles/Article/123973 "`  remove the space just before the
   “ so the link is
`<a href="/articles/Article/123973"`, no error when submitted for approval

This only occurs in the Reference link, a standard link can contain the space and will not error out, for example,

```
<a href="https://cs11.salesforce.com/articles/Article/118966 "
```